# Can Stack Exchange sites be private?

Tags: support, area-51

Are sites proposed on Area 51 allowed restrict access to a group of people smaller/more specific than "the general public"?  For example: only registered users of an existing web app?

Comment: Why the down vote? I didn't know and i couldn't find the answer..

Comment: On meta, people usually vote down if they don't want to see what you're proposing, not for "stupid questions" like on Stack Overflow and the likes. That's what I understood of it anyway..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: [**Stack Overflow Enterprise is now available**](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/enterprise) for internal use.

*original message:*

---

No. Stack Exchange 2.0 is [only for public, community-driven sites](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/).

Answer (score 1):

You can however set up your own [Stack Overflow clone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones/37953#37953).